# PhpStorm - problem with spaces in tag names (version 2020.3)

Tags: phpstorm

I have problem after updating PhpStorm to version 2020.3. If I write for example:

`<div id`... PhpStorm repairs it to `<divid` and delete my spaces inner tags.

Can you help me how can I fixed it?

Comment: I write <div id> and after i click on space, phpstorm delete it. I dont understand it. It is problem only inner tags

Comment: Now is fixed. It was "latte" plugin for nette. Probably not compatible with new version phpstorm.